# Can I privately share a draft question?

Tags: support

I've been working on a question and would like a friend to review it before I post it. Is there a way to post it as a private draft so I can share it? I was going to share on Github but it doesn't have the same markdown formatter as here.

Posting and self-closing/deleting doesn't allow you to share the link right?

Comment: If you self-delete you can only share with someone with 10k+ rep. GFM isn't *that* different, they can probably give you useful feedback via e.g. a Gist. But drafts aren't stored on the server, there's nothing to share.

Comment: Posting and self-closing is not possible, however self-deleting is. You could then share the link. **However**, it will probably lead to you getting question banned over time if your questions do not end up being posted. There is no current way to accomplish what you are looking for. It has been discussed before though, and I for one would think that draft sharing is beneficial.

Comment: If you just want them to provide comments, you could just take a screenshot of the post and send that to them for review

Comment: You could create a team. If you create it now, it'll always be free for up to 10 users. That's the only way to privately share questions on-site afaik.

Comment: @NickA Well Indeed, although it's a long question, too long for a screenshot. I can just save the rendered HTML and share it that way though (although ctrl+s in Chrome doesn't give me the most up to date version for some reason)

Comment: Can't you create a [Secret Gist](https://gist.github.com/rschrieken/64a207b542dff454613d792ca8498f39) on GitHub? It does support markdown.

Comment: @rene Different markdown formatter, it's messed up all my 2 level bullet point lists

Comment: You can use https://stackedit.io/editor. Not related to me. But I use it to store a brunch of my draft question before they hit the live

Comment: I don't have anything specific to share but this is a use case we're talking about and want to solve. If folks add their thoughts on this I'll be sure to follow the discussion. :)

Answer (score 14):

Send your friend your markdown (via email, Github, it doesn't matter), and tell them that they can preview it by copying and pasting it into the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) page or in the answer box to any question (which might be better if your friend doesn't have a SO account).

As long as your friend doesn't accidentally post it, there are no downsides to doing it this way. It's also truly private.

Answer (score 5):

The technical difficulty here is avoiding a large amount of content posted as "draft" by users if it were to be supported.

Placing it on another exchange, for example draft.stackexchange.com, would be one route to go, however, that would be obscure, and more than likely lead to no one using it or being used so sparingly that it makes no sense to retain. In addition, it could be very difficult to moderate. So, while in theory it could be possible, in practice it should probably be avoided.

This leaves us with the only option being to integrate it directly into the current exchange, Stack Overflow in this case. Any time platform level changes are made like this, there is an inherent risk so balancing out the risk of introducing a relatively large feature versus the reward of who will benefit is difficult.

Introducing a draft question feature pros/cons:

Pros:

- Allows users to ask peers for help without cluttering the site
- Allows editing by the OP prior to release
- Potentially allows for a review queue to oversee help
- Fits in with the previous path of "Mentorship" that was trialed
- Prevents low quality content from being posted to some degree

Cons:

- Feature development time which could be spent somewhere more beneficial
- Risk of spam
- Risk of waste from non use
- Risk of bloat due to drafts never being posted

As such, the draft feature must essentially only allow each user *one* draft at most. Sharing it publicly will be the only option, as private sharing will require more development than the feature warrants; as well, Stack Overflow doesn't really support private spaces.

There is only one ideal place for this to reside, which would be in the user profile. Adding a tab, similar to Developer Story, which was just an instance of the markdown editor instead of the Developer Story interface, and which was managed through a user settings flag as private (non shareable, only the user can see it) / public, could work.

This would:

- prevent any user from spamming with the feature, as it would be relatively hidden (attached to their profile - optionally)
- allow an easy path for sharing the draft: https://stackoverflow.com/users/draft/1026459
- create a little bit of space for joy (never underestimate the value of joy) for those who would perhaps want to use the draft as an expansion of their profile for fun or the like
- be easy to implement as it is extremely similar to the current implementation of Developer Story

As a solution, I think it works. However, that this is a problem which needs to be solved may be another issue entirely.

Here is what it that might like:

[image: Mock up of profile draft]

Comment: Couple of follow-up questions. Can you describe what spam (or other abuse) risks you see? What about just no-indexing / unlisting "draft" questions as something in-between public and private? Also one comment: Love thinking about ways to make little spaces of joy -- nice add. :)

Comment: @MeganRisdal - Sure. Spam here is always a risk, it is just that there is a lot of tooling that helps fight it. Perhaps spamming a feature which essentially allows a user to create a non indexed post doesn't get exposure, but it will create resource load from a technical aspect. Maybe throttling can handle that, but even still, if gamed it could add up. So, spam risks would be mostly of the wasted resource end, especially if the spammer could create them at will.

Comment: @MeganRisdal - As far as general abuse of a draft feature, where there was no limit on how many a user could create, there would be the risk of leaving the sphere of Stack Overflow and accidentally creating a space where pastebin-esque use begins to occur. Combating this would more than likely entail creating reputation limits on drafts, which unfortunately would limit the benefit to new users, who arguably benefit the most from drafts. I think a draft would need to be a sort of high order resource that users could not consume much of.

Comment: @MeganRisdal - Thanks for liking the note on joy :) Sid Meier told me that once.

Comment: Great! This is really helpful. Thanks for taking the time to share your thoughts! I am not familiar with the issues Pastebin encounters around this so I'll do some digging to learn more about that -- thanks for the lead!

Answer (score 3):

**An <kbd>Export Preview</kbd> button in the editor** would suffice for me.

This would be available when asking/editing/answering or anything else which uses this box I'm typing in. Its job would be to export the rendered contents of the preview section (probably as HTML).

Pros:

- Doesn't require an additional place to save drafts (above what we [already have](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66238/354801))
- Exports the latest version (for some reason Ctrl+S in Chrome doesn't always give me the HTML of the latest draft)

Cons:

- Read-only (but that's all I'm after)
- Might make it easier to pull content off SO with web-scrapers (I assume there are measures in place to stop this more generally, but easier exporting could exacerbate things, I don't know)

---

I'm concerned a PDF would require extra effort (what to do about code blocks with scroll bars etc.) and would end up looking like an implementation of [StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com/), so perhaps some rendered HTML would be better.

Comment: The pdf is already built into the browser. Simply use print, and then for destination choose "save as pdf". No code block scroll bar support, although you can use the tidy button to remove that for the most part.

Answer (score 2):

I use an editor called MacDown 2 (It's Mac specific, but possibly helpful, so I'll share this). MacDown 2 utilizes the same Markdown syntax with certain allowed HTML elements that we use, and it gives you an on-the-fly preview.

You can export whatever's in the preview a variety of ways, including PDF or rendered HTML (it supports some custom styles too). I'm a ***huge*** fan of composing my question offline and editing, and I use the PDF feature to share drafts privately. Depending on the question, I sometimes work on the draft for several days.

Typora and others are also really good for this workflow and many are cross-platform. Private paste services like ybin allow you to share the raw markdown, and your collaborators just need to have an editor with a live preview similar to the one you use.

Prior to the community team having access to a development instance of a team where we can just publish drafts as questions, we used this method (though we'd use Google docs to share the markdown, which was almost always not optimal).

If someone were to write a good collaborative web-based markdown editor they would do well. Some have come and gone; I guess they're just difficult to break even or make money with.